# Find trigger word and add class to div if text in this div have this word

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys hope for your help!
Need a seach trigger word in text on page and add class if text have 1 or more of this words
Thanks!)

```js
let triggers = [
"hello",
"fint",
"wasssup",
"city",
"apple"
];


$('.parent-div .phrase').each(function(i,elem) {



        // if ( 1 or more words - triggers find in <p> ) {


            //add new class to all div`s with class .parent-div


        // }

    
    
});
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> city of Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> Lorem Hello world Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you give us more to work with. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask preferably have an expected output and a block of code that we are able to reproduce without writing original code ourselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScripts `.includes()`, see code snippet.

```js
let triggers = [
"hello",
"fint",
"wasssup",
"city",
"apple"
];

$('.parent-div .phrase').each(function(e) {
  if (triggers.some(v => $(this).text().includes(v))) {
    $(this).parent().addClass('triggered');
  }
});
```

```css
.triggered {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> city of Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
  <div class="parent-div"><p class="phrase"> Lorem Hello world Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if God has name, his name is Savado :D
 
Thanks!

Comment: @ВладимирСолёный If you would be so kind to upvote the answer, I will reach my next milestone of 500 reputation points :)